# Email Deliverability

Tags: email

Our site sends out transactional emails once an order is complete. Is there a way to see why some are not delivered? I have tried a few different third-party SMTP services Amazon SES, DuoCircle) and have added them to my SPF record and used DKIM. The email X-spam scores aren't very high at all (1.1/11 is generally the highest). If we manually forward our copy of the order it gets to them just fine but just not when sending from the site. We are using TLS as well. Thing is that apparently they aren't even going to spam/junk - they just don't arrive. Any ideas on how to see what is actually happening along the way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to be a programming related issue as written

Answer (score 0):

On a good Email Relay Service you can set webhooks for derliverd and bounced messages. If you save the webhook response to the order you have the information is delivered successful. When you forward the mail manually is the same mailserver and domain?

You can check the mailserver config with this tool. Send one mail to a test address manually and a other from the site.

https://emailsocket.com/ (checkout 2 test addresses)